# understanding the code

Tags: c++, reference

Can some one explain me this code
there is a class `StringStream` . What i don't get is `StringStream& write(char*)`.
and if in cpp file there is

```
StringStream& StringStream::write(char* text)
{
   //what values can i return??
   //can i return address of character text is currently pointing to?
}
```

Comment: You're probably supposed to return `*this`.

Answer (score 4):

You'd return `*this` - i.e. a reference to the current object. (Well, you can return any non-local `StringStream`, but I guess the purpose is the one I stated)

This technique is usually used for method chaining - i.e. doing something like:

```
StringStream ss;
ss.write("Hello ").write("world!");
```

Comment: You would return a reference of StringStream. sorry didn't see Luchian commented :D nevermind

Comment: ...the reason being to enable chaining (`stream.write("hello").write(" world");`).

Comment: Oh... you edited your post to give the exact same example... +1

Comment: Actually, the reason to implement that function is to be able to do chaining. But how should i implement that function, in order to be able to do chaining? or how does that work?

Comment: @cybercop exactly as you did it, and returning `*this` from the function.

Comment: @cybercop "Actually, the reason to implement that function is to be able to do chaining." -- your opening sentence seems utterly unrelated to this answer or the other comments.  "Actually" implies disagreement...

Comment: @cybercop the only thing you need for chaining is to `return *this`. As to implementing the function correctly, that is a different matter (and cannot be answered without knowing more details about the class).

Comment: may b i'll ask another question and explain what exactly i want to achieve by implementing method chaining. I didn't even know method chaining till now :P @juanchopanza

Answer (score 3):

This is a method that most likely modifies a `StringStream` instance, and returns a reference to a `StringStream`. So you should return a reference to the instance itself

```
StringStream& StringStream::write(char* text)
{
  // do stuff
  return *this;
}
```

This allows you to perform chaining:

```
StringStream s;
s.write("foo").write("bar");
```

That said, I would have expected the `write` method to take a `const char*`:

```
StringStream& write(const char* text);
```

since the method will presumably not modify the data passed to it, and is required in order to be able to correctly pass string literals such as the `"foo"` and `"bar"` in the example.

Comment: Also note that your examples do pass in `const char*` …

Comment: Actually, the reason to implement that function is to be able to do chaining. But how should i implement that function, in order to be able to do chaining? or how does that work?

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig thanks for the edit. I added a sentence about the examples.

Comment: @cybercop You just copy pasted a comment from another answer, and it doesn't make any more sense here.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply return a reference to stringStream class. As you are writing a member function of the same class you can simply return pointer to this. For more info about the StringStream class : [click here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)